# How can I protect my VB.NET App.exe from decompressing?

Tags: vb.net

I made a small program (App.exe) by (Visual Basic Language) that replaces some files, and a place those files in my preject recoures
the problem is when i build the program i can decompressing the App.exe and see those files like a archive with any decompressing software like a WinRAR or 7-zip, and me i don't want that, [this is a image from my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8nZR.png), someone can help me, thanks in advance

Comment: VBA and VB.NET are two different languages, despite sharing significant syntax similarities. The tag descriptions for each explicitly state not to use them for questions about the other. Read the tag descriptions before using them and DO NOT spam irrelevant tags.

Comment: That isn't your application EXE file. That's the ClickOnce installer for your application. Anything you can see inside that is not a resource to begin with because resources are compiled into the application EXE. You need to do a lot more reading to understand what is your project output, what is the published output and what is a resource.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you very much for your answer and the instructions, and I apologize for the tags because I am still new here, i am just want to make a portable application not a setup, thank you again

Comment: Building your project compiles your source files into an application EXE. Publishing your project creates a ClickOnce installer for that application containing that build output. If you don't want an installer, don't publish. Just copy the output from the *bin\Release* folder. Add resources on the *Resources* page of the project properties and access them in code via `My.Resources`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , i already did all wat you said but the problem still, but i fix it  by another thing, the problem coming from an archive _.RAR_ i puted it in the _resources_ ,thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `ConfuserEx` obfuscator (Google it to get that). After encrypting the app with it, it'll be almost impossible to decompile it or get its raw files (resources) even after extraction.

Simply drag and drop your application into it:

[image: ConfuserEx]

Use `Compressing` packer:

[image: Compressor]

And finally protect it:

[image: Protection]

And you're good to go.